# Configuring http://mail.example.com

Tags: redirects, email, webmail

Can I redirect the URL `http://mail.example.com` into webmail similar to `http://webmail.example.com`?

Comment: The simple answer is a potential "Yes". But I feel there must be more to this question. Can you explain a bit more? Have you tried and it has failed? What have you tried?

Comment: Yup! i tried to create a subdomain mail.my-domain.com , but it says the subdomain is already exists. I checked the Advanced DNS settings in cpanel , there is a record in that name ,but how to give a url for it

Answer (score 1):

The "mail" subdomain is usually used to point to your POP/IMAP/SMTP server so that you configure your mail client easily.    The "webmail" subdomain is usually points to a different machine that allows your user to check their email with a web browser.

The only way this will work is if you have a web server running on the "mail" machine and you have some control over it.  That isn't the case for me.  My hosting company doesn't run a web server on their mail machines.

If you have a web server on the "mail" machine, you just need to put a redirect rule into the *.htaccess* file on that machine.

Answer (score 1):

The `mail` "subdomain" (possibly just a `CNAME` record in DNS) is probably set up by default on your hosting account. AFAIK this is just a convenience. The `mail` subdomain is the expected default when setting up an email clients SMTP and POP3 settings and several programs will default to this.

Whilst this DNS record is present you will struggle to setup the required subdomain/redirect.

You might be able to simply delete this DNS record (if you have access). However, it's probably best to query this with your webhost.